# WeakValueDictionary setdefault without creating a default that won't be used

Tags: python, weak-references

I'm using a `WeakValueDictionary` with `setdefault`, and I would like to be able to *not* create the instance of the thing that's the default

```
import weakref
my_dict = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

# ...

# Will create an instance of MyBigFancyClass even if it's not used 
value = my_dict.setdefault('my-key', default=MyBigFancyClass())
```

How can I avoid creating `MyBigFancyClass` in the cases when it's not used?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setdefault`, you could use a `try/except` block, or I would personally prefer overriding `__getitem__` directly:

```
import weakref

class MyBigFancyClass:
    pass

class MyWeakValueDictionary(weakref.WeakValueDictionary):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = MyBigFancyClass()
            return value

my_dict = MyWeakValueDictionary()
value = my_dict['my-key']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `setdefault`, and roll-your-own using `KeyError`

```
import weakref
my_dict = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

# ...

try:
    value = my_dict['my-key']
except KeyError:
    value = MyBigFancyClass()
    my_dict['my-key'] = value
```